# How many SFMC prospect focused journeys do you have running at any given time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm new to SFMC Journey Builder and am wondering how many prospect acquisition focused journeys most people have running at any given time. We intend to start small with just a few journeys but are debating about whether we should start by focusing on the largest audiences or smaller audiences with higher conversion potential. I imagine that the answer to that question is largely dependent on how many journeys we think we will ultimately have.  If you had to choose between the following 3 options which would you choose and why:

1. Three journeys specific to your prospects' behavior (e.g. visited webpage, downloaded guide, sales opportunities lost) - all audiences mutually exclusive
2. Three journeys specific to the prospects' inferred area of interest (e.g. hiring top talent, topic B, topic C) - some overlap between audiences but 1 nurture at a time
3. Nine journey's combining both 1 & 2 above (e.g. visited hiring top talent webpage, downloaded guide on hiring top talent, closed lost a sales opportunity focused on hiring top talent, visited topic B webpage, downloaded guide on topic B, closed lost a sales opportunity focused on topic B, ….) - overlap between audiences but 1 nurture at a time

Thank you in advance for any thoughts you can share on this!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.